# Secure PDF's generated with Microsoft Access OutputTo

Tags: ms-access, security, pdf

I have an application in Microsoft Access 2007 which generates PDF files via OutputTo ... acFormatPDF. It works fine, but now, someone has manipulated a generated PDF and I now will add a protection for the PDF's to my program code. How can I do that because the OutputTo seems to have no options for doing that? The only protection I need is for changing the document. All other protections (copy, print, ...) have no relevance.

Comment: Do you have Adobe Pro?

Comment: Just realized I totally omitted the product name.  I mean, do you have Adobe Acrobat Reader, Acrobat Standard, or Acrobat Professional?

Comment: I have all of these licenses. I found after some goggling, that I have to use Acrobat Distiller's PdfDistiller6 object with the FileToPDF2 Methode, it has a parameter for switching on security. The security itself must be set in Acrobat Distillers Settings before. But that means my customers must also have a full license of Adobe Acrobat. Is that right?

Comment: That's basically the catch - you have to define a security policy in Acrobat before you can apply it in code.  I have a solution that might work for you if you have Acrobat Standard or Professional, so I'll post it in case it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a method for applying protection to PDFs using [AcroJS](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/pdf/javascript/AcroJS.pdf) and the list of instantiateable COM classes found [here](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/iac_developer_guide.pdf).  I use "CreateObject" to perform late binding of the Acrobat objects, but if you have Acrobat installed, you can add a reference in your project by going into the VBA IDE and clicking Tools ---> References... and checking the box next to "Adobe Acrobat x.x Type Library" (where x.x is your version of Acrobat).  If you don't see that available, look for "acrobat.tlb" in Program Files and add it via the Browse...

```
Public Sub ProtectPDF(strFilePath As String, strPolicyName As String)
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim oPDDoc As Object
    Dim oJso As Object
    Dim oSec As Object
    Dim arrPolicies As Variant
    Dim PolicyIndex As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim success As Boolean
    Const PDSaveFull = 1
    Set oPDDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    If oPDDoc.Open(strFilePath) Then

        Set jso = oPDDoc.GetJSObject

        Set sec = jso.security

        apols = sec.getSecurityPolicies()

        PolicyIndex = -1

        For i = 0 To UBound(arrPolicies)
            If arrPolicies(i).Name = strPolicyName Then
                 PolicyIndex = i
            End If
        Next

        If Not PolicyIndex = -1 Then
            jso.encryptUsingPolicy (arrPolicies(PolicyIndex))
        Else
            Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, "ProtectPDF", "Could not find Policy named: """ & strPolicyName & """"
        End If

        success = oPDDoc.Save(PDSaveFull, strFilePath)

        oPDDoc.Close
    Else
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 2, "ProtectPDF", "Failed to open " & strFilePath
    End If
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    'Handle any Adobe errors here...
End Sub
```