# Sending access form as pdf with pdf restrict editing feature

Tags: ms-access, pdf, outlook, password-protection, ms-access-forms

I have an application in Microsoft Access which sends forms as  PDF files via DoCmd.SendObject to outlook. It works fine, but now, I want to add protection (restrict editing) for the PDF's to my program code. How can I do that because of the DoCmd.SendObject seems to have no options for doing that? The only protection I need is for editing the document and not for opening and printing pdf.

Comment: Or maybe this one helps [Prompt for Password when creating PDF within MS Access Code](https://forums.pdfforge.org/t/prompt-for-password-when-creating-pdf-within-ms-access-code/5929/5)

Comment: The first link is broken and the second won't help. @Rene

Comment: I removed the 1st link as I couldn't edit it. This should work: [Secure PDF's generated with Microsoft Access OutputTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248538/secure-pdfs-generated-with-microsoft-access-outputto)